# Python3.6: pool.map throws -- AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing

Please find the code and exception below, I tried digging stackoverflow but couldn't identify why pool.map is throwing this exception.

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from transformers import pipeline
import os


def parallelize_dataframe(df, func,num_partitions,num_cores):
    a,b,c,d,e = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, [a,b,c,d,e]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
 

def get_doc(text,**kwargs):
    nlp = kwargs['nlp_obj']
    result = nlp(question="Which type of doctor does the patient consult?", context=text)
    return result['answer']

def square(x):
    return x**2
 
def test_func(data):
    nlp = pipeline("question-answering")
    data["HCP"] = data["text"].apply(get_doc,nlp_obj = nlp)
    return data
 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_partitions = 5
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
    data = data[['text']]
    data = data[data['text'].isna() == False]
    data.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    data = data.loc[:10]
    test = parallelize_dataframe(data, test_func,num_partitions,num_cores)
    print(test)
```

> in parallelize_dataframe(df, func,
> num_partitions, num_cores)
> 10     a,b,c,d,e = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
> 11     pool = Pool(num_cores)
> ---> 12     df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, [a,b,c,d,e]))
> 13     pool.close()
> 14     pool.join()
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func,
> iterable, chunksize)
> 264         in a list that is returned.
> 265         '''
> --> 266         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
> 267
> 268     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
> 642             return self._value
> 643         else:
> --> 644             raise self._value
> 645
> 646     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children